# Can we know the address list which blockchain API has created?

Tags: blockchain, api, payment

I am currently using blockchain payment API. This API has created the addresses for receiving payment. 
https://blockchain.info/api/api_receive

Can we know the list of unused addresses this blockchain API has created.
I know we can know the number of gap(unused addresses), but I would like to know the detail addresses.
I checked Setting->Addresses->Managed Addresses on my blockchain wallet account. However, could not fine these information. Only a few addressed are listed there.

Your advices are highly appreciated.